# MatplotLib.pyplot.scatter not plotting normally when a new list added to the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I was working with NumPy and Pandas to create some artificial data for testing models.
First, I coded this:

```
# Constructing some random data for experiments

import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(42)

# Rectangular Data

total_n = 500
x = np.random.rand(total_n)*10
y = np.random.rand(total_n)*10

divider = 260

# Two lambda functions are for shifting the data, the numbers are chosen arbitrarily
f = lambda a: a*2
x[divider:] = f(x[divider:])
y[divider:] = f(y[divider:])

g = lambda a: a*3 + 5
x[:divider] = g(x[:divider])
y[:divider] = g(y[:divider])

# Colours array for separating the data
colors = ['blue']*divider + ['red']*(total_n-divider)

squares = np.array([x,y])

plt.scatter(squares[0],squares[1], c=colors, alpha=0.5)
```

I got what I wanted:
[The Data I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6qCQ.png)

But I wanted to add the colors array to the numpy array, to take it as a *Label* variable so I added this to the code:

```
# Constructing some random data for experiments

import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(42)

# Rectangular Data

total_n = 500
x = np.random.rand(total_n)*10
y = np.random.rand(total_n)*10

divider = 260

# Two lambda functions are for shifting the data, the numbers are chosen arbitrarily
f = lambda a: a*2
x[divider:] = f(x[divider:])
y[divider:] = f(y[divider:])

g = lambda a: a*3 + 5
x[:divider] = g(x[:divider])
y[:divider] = g(y[:divider])

# Colours array for separating the data
colors = ['blue']*divider + ['red']*(total_n-divider)

squares = np.array([x,y,colors])

plt.scatter(squares[0],squares[1], c=colors, alpha=0.5)
```

And everything just blows out:
[The Blown out Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHnD6.png)

I got my work around this by separating the label from the whole numpy array. But still what's going on here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I think I have the answer. A [Numpy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) can only have one type of data which is infered when creating the array if it is not given. When you create squares with colors in it, then `squares.dtype='<U32'`, which means that all values are converted to a little-endian 32 character string.

To avoid that you can:

- use a simple list
- use a pandas dataframe, as they accept columns of different types
- if you want to use numpy you can use a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) as follow

  ```
  zipped = [z for z in zip(x, y, colors)]
  #input must be a list of tuples/list representing rows
  #the transformation is made with zip

  dtype = np.dtype([('x', float), ('y', float), ('colors', 'U10')])
  #type of data, 10 characters string is U10
  squares  = np.array(zipped, dtype=dtype)
  #creating the array by precising the type

  plt.scatter(squares["x"],squares["y"], c=squares["colors"], alpha=0.5)
  #when plotting call the corresponding column, just as in a dataframe
  ```